# Standard normal distribution is truncated to the left by 2

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Would you please show me how to write the pdf distributions of the following

Standard normal distribution is truncated to the left by 2

Exponential distribution is truncated to the left by 2

Cauchy distribution is truncated to the left by 2

i do not know what does mean by truncated to the left by 2

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "write"?  You have already successfully described these distributions, so evidently you have some other form of description in mind, but what is it specifically? The CDF, PDF, CCDF, MGF, CF, CGF, survival function, hazard function, ...?

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking for seems to be the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $X \geq c$ so we can start by deriving the distribution function,

\begin{align}
P(X \leq t \mid X \geq c) &= \frac{P(c \leq X \leq t)}{P(X \geq c)} \\
&= \frac{P(X \leq t) - P(X < c)}{P(X \geq c)} 
\end{align}

for $t \geq c$ and zero otherwise.  To get the density function we just differentiate the above with respect to $t$,

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} P(X \leq t \mid X \geq c) &= \frac{f(t)}{P(X \geq c)}
\end{align}

where $f$ is the density function of the untruncated distribution, again setting $f(t) = 0$ for $t < c$.

Comment: I JUST NEED THE PDF IN GENERAL

Comment: @FAHAD That's what I gave you.